# Problem in "show unanswered"

Tags: bug, mobile-web

If you select "show unanswered" then it displays "show Votes":

[image]

But the sorting is by *unanswered*. If you go to the second page, the sorting goes by the *votes*:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The *All Questions* page is different from the *Search* page. The *Questions* page has the following tabs:

- *Newest*
- *Active*
- Bountied
- Unanswered
- Frequent
- *Votes*

The Search results page only has the following tabs:

- *Relevant*
- *Newest*
- *Active*
- *Votes*

Note that in both of the above lists, those in *italics* are sorts, and not filters. You'll notice that in search results you only have access to sorting, not filtering.

If you want to *search* for unanswered questions, you need to specify that in your search with `hasaccepted:no`, so your search body would be: [`show voices hasaccepted:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=show+voices+hasaccepted%3Ano)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a broken user flow. As a user, i visit All questions tab and filter by Unanswered. I see questions which are Unanswered and sorted by Votes, which is expected. But this filtered results page is a paginated view. Browsing through paginated pages should not change the filter criteria. I have never seen such a behavior in paginated view in any app. As rightly pointed out by @Danis, the 2nd page of the results page incorrectly show 2nd page of All questions sorted by Votes. Unanswered filter is lost, which breaks user flow.

Comment: Besides, this erroneous behavior is only with mobile site. On Desktop view, this works as expected. The 2nd page url in Desktop is https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=unanswered&page=2 which gives expected results. But 2nd page on mobile view is https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=Votes&pagesize=15 which gives unexpected results.

Comment: You've also mentioned that Unanswered is not a sort criteria. But when user hits All questions tab followed by filtering with Unanswered, the url generated is https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered . This is obviously erroneous url because Unanswered value shouldn't be assigned to "sort" parameter at all.